# Webstorm - Link html class reference to scss file

Tags: intellij-idea, sass, compass-sass, webstorm, partials

I've setup a compass file watcher as listed here. 
http://blog.founddrama.net/2013/04/watching-compass-files-in-webstorm/

The file watcher works flawlessly, same as the command line compass process.

I'm curious if there's a way to configure WebStorm to point to references in the .scss file instead of the compiled app.css file.

Example

Inside index.html i have

`<a href='#' class='pandaStyle'>`

When i click on pandaStyle, it takes me to the line inside the compiled app.css

I'd like it to take me to the partial of _animalStyle.scss

Comment: not currently possible; please vote for [this issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-6737)

Answer (score 0):

As @Iena said, it's not possible. Try voting for the issue (http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-6737) and JetBrains may add the feature.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem like this:
Adding

```
@import "myFolder/myCssStylesheet";
```

to the .scss file and get all css classes and Id's from that stylesheet.
For example:

```
@import "Styles/bootstrap.css";
```

gives me all **bootstrap** classes autocomplite in my .scss files